# when installing a package with package.el, How to never show the compile log buffer?

Tags: package

This buffer annoys me every time I install a new package or update one with package.el:

[image: screen-shot of the buffer]

How can I tell to emacs that never ever show that buffer unless I need to know something really important from it?

Comment: You should not suppress it.  It contains valuable information, highlight errors in the compilation process.

Comment: Agreed.  You should rather bug maintainers to write warning-free code.

Comment: Pradhan: Can't comment here yet, but the user didn't ask that there not be warnings. He asked that the frame with the warnings not open up. He may well want to review the compile log later. andrew-swann: You don't necessarily know what the user is trying to achieve. For example, I find popping open the buffer disrupts my flow. I found this thread because I was trying to install N packages, and I wanted to check the warnings at the end. What would be ideal would be to have the buffer pop up optionally, and display "N warnings, M errors" in the minibuffer. In any case, don't tell users who want

Comment: Customize `display-buffer-alist`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `package--compile` is calling `byte-recompile-directory`(default), you can turn off all warnings by customizing the variable `byte-compile-warnings`. You can either set it to `nil` yourself, or use `M-x customize-group` on the group `bytecomp`, set `Byte Compile Warnings` to `Some` and check none of the boxes. However, if you have `package--compile` being `defadvice`d to invoke something else(`async-byte-recompile-directory` in my case), you should look into the customization of that specific function/library.

If you are using `async-bytecomp`, I have raised a request [here](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async/issues/44) to inject the `bytecomp` customizations into the environment it compiles in. You could make do with a local change until there's a resolution : Add

```
(async-inject-variables "\\`byte-compile-warnings\\'")
```

after

```
,(async-inject-variables "\\`load-path\\'")
```

in `async-bytecomp.el`.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

> set-window-dedicated-p is a built-in function in `C source code'.
>
> (set-window-dedicated-p WINDOW FLAG)
>
> Mark WINDOW as dedicated according to FLAG. WINDOW must be a live
>   window and defaults to the selected one.  FLAG non-nil means mark
>   WINDOW as dedicated to its buffer.  FLAG nil means mark WINDOW as
>   non-dedicated.  Return FLAG.

You may be interested by setting the installation window [dedicated](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html), then the compilation buffer will no more bother you when inside the dedicated window.